# Is the equal symbol in an infinite series misleading notation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, notation

The infinite series in this notation: $$\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\dots = 1$$
is nothing more than the limit of the partial sums in:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n}}$$
The initial notation implies to beginner students that somehow we are "summing a number of non-ending terms" and they magically give the result of 1.   Although that is not the case, since it does not make sense to 'add' (in the conventional sense) a non-ending sequence of numbers (as it never ends). (or have I misunderstood that?)

Is the usage of the equal symbol in the first notation misleading/wrong? If not, then what does the equal symbol really mean?

Edit: Note: I do, of course, agree with the result of the summation and I understand the result. I am just wondering about the appropriateness of the notation.

Comment: Do you agree that $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{2^n}=1$? Well, we just denote the left hand side by $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}$. So we simply define a sum of infinitely many elements in this way. It's a definition, so it can't be wrong. Of course that will look weird to a person who never seen it before, but after seeing the definition there is really nothing too deep here. Until now we worked only with sums of finitely many numbers, now we generalize it and define an infinite sum. (and if you think of it, this definition makes perfect sense)

Comment: The equals symbol is perfectly correct and not misleading, but your objection might be applied to the notation $\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots,$ since this notation is (arguably) not well defined.

Comment: Is the question about ellipsis though? Just as $\frac13 =^? 0.333\ldots$ and $e =^? 2.718281828\ldots$ which are also infinite sums of digits, maybe you would think these should be $\ne$ too?

Comment: @DavidK Can you please elaborate what do you mean by "not well defined"?

Comment: To be completely clear, one might write $$\frac12 + \frac14 + \frac18 + \cdots + \frac1{2^n} + \cdots,$$ (this might also be what people are saying by "not well-defined") but there are definitely times (e.g. sieves and reindexing come to mind immediately) when the expanded sum might be more sensible to communicate the author's intention than the expression using sigma notation.

Comment: "Arguably" not well defined. Are the terms really all the reciprocals of powers of $2$? Does it really go on forever? We are usually meant to answer "yes" to both of those questions, but you could argue about that with more justification than arguing about the $=$ symbol. After all, if $\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots$ means what we usually mean by it, it is absolutely equal to exactly $1.$ And if it doesn't mean that, then what does it mean?

Comment: You can define it in a certain way to mean absolutely and exactly 1, but without an understanding of limits it seems quite meaningless without a context what  $\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots$ is.  So I'm not exactly objecting on the value of that, but rather the usage of the notation in teaching (to me as a student I mean) as it seems counterintuitive/unprofessional to understanding what it really means.

Comment: @sevenn0 Your most recent comment seems to work equivalently well when replacing $\frac12 + \frac14 + \frac18 + \cdots$ with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{2^n}$.  If your question's purpose really is about pedagogy, then the argument should be about whether having two notations is better than just one, and as I mentioned in my previous comment, there are instances where having a parameter hanging around from the $\Sigma$ notation obscures what we want to show.

Comment: @BrianMoehring  Pedagogy aside; I am genuinely wondering whether the first notation has any meaning without invoking the $\Sigma$ notation after quoting. That is why it seemed to me that the equal sign is misleading*. As it really has no meaning without elaboration/context.  But now that the others explained they are interchangeable and each has its purpose then I can see it from another perspective...

*A popular example comes to mind where people think 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... = -1/12 without a special context because of pop science online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The notation
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n}}
\tag1$$
should be completely explained in any calculus textbook.  The notation
$$
\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+... = 1
\tag2$$
is a dumbed-down version for those who do not know what $\sum$ means, those who have never studied calculus, or other special purposes.  I agree that $(2)$ with no extra explanation can be misleading.

Comment: Sadly, this "notation" is used not only by amateurs. I've seen some professors using this notation in advanced courses.

Comment: Of course, because human beings prefer to communicate in natural ways, rather than in hyper-formal jargons designed for formal verification instead of human communication.

Comment: @JBL While the $\Sigma$ notation might takes a bit of time to get used to (for first year students), it is actually more natural compared to writing long sums.

Comment: @mark Professors use it because he assumes his listeners "know what they means." Nothing really wrong with that. Notation is for communication more often than for rigor.

Comment: @Mark well, depends how advanced it is. I think it is only a first year calc/real analysis course where one ought to be super strict and clear with this particular issue. Below this level, students aren’t able to comprehend the concepts, while above this level, students are expected to know and comfortably define/manipulate the definitions. so yea, 1st year calculus is a weird middle ground.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Of course everyone knows what it means. Though it looked kinda weird, because the general terms there were more complicated than $\frac{1}{2^n}$, and writing with $\Sigma$ would be much shorter. Anyway, I just wanted to point that the end of the answer is not fully correct.

Comment: @Mark I am a professional research mathematician, very attuned to patterns of mathematical communication.  Like all mathematicians, I deploy highly formalized patterns of communication when it is important to communicate an idea rigorously, with no ambiguity, especially in writing.  And, like all other human beings, I deploy less formal patterns of communication when I want someone to follow an idea easily and not get bogged down in technicalities.  There is nothing sad about the latter situation.

Answer (score 3):

An infinite sum is simply shorthand for the limit of a convergent series. You're right in the sense that infinite addition alone is not well-defined. But the limit of a summed series is perfectly well-defined.

Let $(a_n)=(a_1,a_2,...) \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a real sequence. Its *summation series* is a sequence $(s_n)$ defined as $$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k.$$ Now, whether $(s_n)$ converges or not is a different story. When $(s_n)$ is convergent, then $$s^*=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$$ is simply shorthand for $$s^* = \lim_{k \to \infty} s_k,$$ which is a well-defined notion of equation.